# How to copy values from one object to another from constructors in java?

Tags: java, object, variables, methods, constructor

```
public class testing {
     
    String name;
    String aname;

    testing(String n){


       this.name  = n;

    }

    testing(testing s){

        this.aname = s.name;

        
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println(name + "  -first cons");
        System.out.println(aname + "  -second cons");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(" ");


    testing ab = new testing("test");
    testing ab2 = new testing(ab);


    ab2.display();
    ab.display();

    }
}
```

This is the program and i have linked a screenshot of the output with the question.

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxNNS.png)

the first constructor initializes the variable and i made a second constructor to create another object. I wanted to copy the value of the variable from the original variable but i dunno what is happening.
when i tried printing the variables using a method ,  it prints one of the variable at a time while printing null in the other one.

Please help me to solve this problem or guide me through another way of going through this.

I am fairly new to coding so please keep that in mind.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-constructor

Comment: Please don't post links, just paste the output in the question text.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing one of the members in either constructor then print out both - so the one you didn't initialize will be `null`.

What you probably want is

```
class Testing {
 String name;

 public Testing(String aname) {
  name = aname;
 }
 public Testing(Testing source) {
  name = source.name; // or this(source.name)
 }
}
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the copy constructor as such.